# Georeferencing map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am trying to georeference my map, But I am unsure how can I rotate my image so that I can find GCP points easily from map canvas.

In this image North is clearly visible.

Using qgis 3.0.

[image]

Comment: Just rotate it by 90° in any picture manipulation software. Even paint could work.

Comment: This does not solve the GCP issue

Answer (score 5):

There are several tutorials on how to georeference an image. Consider using a search engine with some keywords before asking on this Q&A site.

I typed in georeference + qgis in google and found this QGIS tutorial on [Georeferencing Topo Sheets and Scanned Maps](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a quick 90-degree rotate in paint or whatever, as suggested in the comments. Then you can georeference using J Rectifier plug-in. Here's a video on J Rectifier: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLMvIUtdBJ8

Comment: Problem is after rotating to 90 degrees also when I am opening the image its opening like previous. That's the reason of asking anyway to rotate in georeferencer. Thank you all.

Comment: then it must be an error on saving in paint or whatever you are using to rotate.